# What does the following sentence mean?

Tags: sentence-meaning

> Often taking a prominent position over a whiteboard or across a wall,
>   timelines are one of the most commonplace classroom tools used to
>   teach history. They present a concise chronology with dates and events
>   listed in a linear narrative, forming a skeletal story of history.
>
> Despite their usefulness in allowing students to gain a cursory
>   knowledge of many key moments in the past, their bare-bones,
>   fact-centered structure is symptomatic of the myopic character of
>   curricula that emphasize the What, When, and Who and eclipse the
>   significance of Why and How.

can anybody kindly simplify this sentence ?

Comment: Can you edit this to provide more context and if possible a link to the original source? My interpretation of this sentence is that "their" is the main subject of the sentence, but what "their" stands for is not given in this sentence. It's probably in one of the few sentences proceeding this one in the original source.

Comment: @cjl750 I have edited my question .

Comment: There are lots of questions here. Please identfiy a particular point of concern.

Comment: Please [read this meta discussion](https://ell.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1084/so-you-found-a-sentence-or-phrase-why-you-should-cite-your-source). Then tell us: where did you find this quote?

Answer (score 1):

Traditionally, history is taught by rote memorization of names, dates, and places (the "What, When, and Who").  This gives students a good general knowledge of what happened, but leaves out the details of *why* and *how* it happened.

For example, I might have been taught that the US entered WWII after the Japanese bombed Pearl Harbor on December 7th, 1941. However, few students are taught why the Japanese chose a sneak attack on the US, or why the US had not already entered the war, or how the attack affected Americans afterward.

Your example sentence calls this approach *myopic* and, presumably, goes on to explain a better approach.

Answer (score 1):

> Despite their usefulness in allowing students to gain a cursory knowledge of many key moments in the past, their bare-bones, fact-centered structure is symptomatic of the myopic character of curricula that emphasize the What, When, and Who and eclipse the significance of Why and How.

The main subject of this sentence is "timelines," which is given in the proceeding paragraph:

> Often taking a prominent position over a whiteboard or across a wall, **timelines** are one of the most commonplace classroom tools used to teach history.

A less-verbose reading of the sentence might go something like this:

*Despite how useful timelines are for showing students a lot of important historical moments at a glance, the limited information timelines display can cause students and teachers to focus too much on the basic details of historical events and not enough on why and how those events occurred.*

In my reading, the "big idea" in the original sentence that is somewhat easy to gloss over is "*symptomatic* of the myopic character of *curricula*" – meaning that timelines are just one manifestation (symptom) of a larger problem about school curriculums in general. (Without seeing the source text, we can't tell whether the author is critiquing history curriculums in particular or making a larger critique of the education system across, say, academia as a whole, or liberal arts at large, or across the country.)

So the larger point the author is trying to make is not that timelines are bad, per se, but that education at large (curricula) does not focus enough on teaching *why* and *how* things happen.

Learning and understanding "why" and "how" types of questions requires critical thinking, whereas learning simple details (who, what, when) only requires memorization.

But because education focuses too much on details that can be memorized and not enough on larger ideas that require critical thought, the author contends, we wind up with timelines hanging on our walls rather than some other type of chart that would better highlight the critical *why* and *how* ideas.

A better rewording of the original sentence that includes this big idea, then, might go like this:

*Timelines – despite how useful they are for showing students a lot of important historical moments at a glance – are a poor tool for teachers who would strive to promote a rigorous, thought-provoking curriculum. The fact that we hang timelines on our walls instead of more useful illustrations is a sign that our larger approach to education is flawed.*